# sh: 1: vite: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, laravel, pusher

I have been trying to use pusher in my application. I started receiving this error after I created the `PusherFactory`, as shown on the screenshot. But, I have been receiving the error `undefined type Pusher\Pusher`. So I tried to run install pusher using the following command: `composer require pusher\pusher-php-server`.

After all that, when I try to run `npm install && npm run dev`, I now get this error:

```
> dev
> vite

sh: 1: vite: Permission denied
patrick@patrick-nthiwa:~/Music/primecrm/prime$ sudo npm run dev
[sudo] password for patrick: 

*
sh: 1: vite: Permission denied*
```

Comment: Probably the root cause is that you used `sudo` when you created `vite` (too); you need to understand what `sudo` does. Basically never use it in your home directory to create files or directories which end up not belonging to you.

Answer (score 48):

A simple re-installing of packages did the trick for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for my Qwik project.

Comment: Damn, thanks. I tried to `rm -rf node_modules` before I realized the directory doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me on MacBook:

```
sudo chmod +x node_modules/.bin/vite
```

Comment: `chmod +x` gives not only the user (you) execute permission, but also all members of the file's group; not sure why one would want that. Also, `sudo` is unnecessary if you are the owner of the file. More precise would be `chmod u+x path/to/executable` or `chmod 744 ...` to give everyone else read-only access.

Answer (score 5):

Install vite globally using the command worked:

```
npm install -g vite
```

Comment: Worked on a project that moved from windows to mac

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying several possible solutions. But nothing worked for me.
I currently use WSL and NVM for nodejs and npm.
My GIT installation is on WSL and not on Windows.

These are the steps that worked for me.

1. Update GIT and then update any Linux distribution packages you have installed on WSL. In my case, Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

2. Update nodejs from nvm to the latest stable version (Today: nodejs 18.17.1 and npm 9.6.7).

```
$ nvm install --lts
```

3. In your project folder, change the version of node, to use the newly installed version (in my case, this won't affect my project, but it would be nice if you evaluate it).

```
$ nvm use --lts
```

4. Remove de node_modules folder from your project and reinstall npm in it (maybe you should close the console before reinstalling npm).

```
$ rm -r node_modules
$ npm install
```

5. Rerun the development server.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the access rights to the project folder

```
chown -R username /path/to/folder
```

or giving 777 to all files and folders that means all your files and directories will be readable, writable and executable

```
chmod -R 777/path/to/folder
```

Comment: While this may work, it is using brute force. You may see unrelated consequences later. Permissions exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, you should first uninstall Node and then reinstall it. I encountered the same problem, and the issue was resolved after uninstalling Node.

Using Homebrew:

```
brew install node
```

Answer (score -2):

This is what I finally did and it worked.

1.) I installed node scripts using the following command:

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

2.) Then update composer:

```
composer update
```

3.) Then I installed npm:

```
npm install
```

4.) Run the dev command:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: There is no link between `composer` and `npm` which is two different environment : the first one a dependency manager for PHP and the second one for nodejs package manager